# Create guest account with restricted access to applications

Tags: arch-linux, users, account-restrictions, guest-account

I'm trying to create a guest account in arch linux that only allows the user to use simple applications like firefox. I do not want them to have access to programs like terminal or grub-customizer etc. How would I do this?

Comment: Depending on your user interface requirements, you may want "kiosk mode", where by default the system automatically logs in a user that can only run a web browser. A good way to do this (for Ubuntu) is in http://askubuntu.com/questions/124759/customize-ubuntu-for-a-library-internet-kiosk. The details for Arch are probably similar.

Comment: Well what I'm trying to do is setup a dummy account on my laptop which launches a reverse ssh tunnel on login. I've had a laptop stolen so I'm pretty paranoid now. I'd like the dummy account to have as little access as possible. I've hidden my main login on gdm.

Comment: Search for [tag:kiosk] questions. This question may well be a duplicate.

Comment: What is your desktop environment? If gnome I will be able to point you in the right direction. I have literally done just the same except the ssh-tunnel which is a great idea! I have collected quite a bit of information on said subject :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of gnome - please use the following as a support in getting where you want to be.

Security
Disable access to any command line

https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/lockdown-command-line.html.en

Ensure that the installation works as wanted before activating this
or ensure that one can log in as root with the right password.  Preferably disable all access to command-line completely. Thus  devices cannot be altered once installed except through chroot.

Disable user list at login screen

[How to disable the user list on GDM3 login screen?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205058/how-to-disable-the-user-list-on-gdm3-login-screen/205065#205065)'

Disable repartitioning for the user

https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/lockdown-repartitioning.html.en

Disable altering settings

https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/dconf-lockdown.html.en

Disable the user from saving files:

https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/lockdown-file-saving.html.en

Disable printing (such as from firefox or libreoffice)

https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/lockdown-printing.html.en

No keyring package installed

You can also lockdown mozilla firefox settings - or at least you used to. Try googling the subject.

Answer (score 1):

Yes basically the howto's from Ubuntu or Mint are the same way to go in Arch. Arch is more of a hands on development system. Not really intended as a stable release for a Kiosk type account. But it can be done. Get your chmod commands right and adduser and passwd settings right and test them.