# Create guest account in Gnome 3.X on Arch Linux

Tags: gnome3, accounts, guest-account

I want a guest account just like in Ubuntu which has following features:

1. It does not require password to login
2. A new home folder (in `/tmp` if possible) is created with no data every time
3. User data is deleted as soon as he/she logs out
4. User can not use `sudo`

I am running Gnome 3.20 on Arch Linux

**NOTE:** please don't close my question as duplicate of [Create guest account with restricted access to applications](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157187/create-guest-account-with-restricted-access-to-applications) because that question does not have   answers to my 2nd and 3rd point

Comment: This is relevant. Perhaps even a dupe if the answer works for you: [Create guest account with restricted access to applications](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/205418).

Comment: @terdon it looks like a work around and not exactly like Ubuntu

Comment: I have no idea how Ubuntu does it. If you need "exactly like Ubuntu", you'll have to [edit] your question and explain what that means. However, the links provided in the linked answer give the ways you can limit a user's authority and are almost certainly how Ubuntu has implemented whatever they've implemented behind the scenes. Try it.

Answer (score 11):

It turns out it's quite simple with GDM. I assume you're using GDM since you're also using Gnome. First, create the `guest` user account with a blank password:

```
sudo useradd -d /tmp/guest -p $(openssl passwd "") guest
```

The `openssl passwd ""` [will return](http://www.slashroot.in/how-are-passwords-stored-linux-understanding-hashing-shadow-utils) the hash of the empty string, thereby setting the password to blank.

Now, all you need are these two scripts:

- `/etc/gdm/PostLogin/Default`

This is executed after you log in and will create the `/tmp/$guestuser` (`/tmp/guest` by default) directory and copy the default files from `/etc/skel` to it. To change the default username for the guest user, set `guestuser` to something else at the beginning.

```
 <!-- language: lang-bash -->

    #!/bin/sh

    guestuser="guest"

    ## Set up guest user session
    if [ "$USER" = "$guestuser" ]; then
        mkdir /tmp/"$guestuser"
        cp /etc/skel/.* /tmp/"$guestuser"
        chown -R "$guestuser":"$guestuser" /tmp/"$guestuser"
    fi
    exit 0
```

- `/etc/gdm/PostSession/Default`

This is executed after you log out and will remove the `/etc/$guestuser` directory and all its contents. Make sure to set `guestuser` to the same value in both scripts.

```
 <!-- language: lang-bash -->

    #!/bin/sh

    guestuser="guest"

    ## Clear up the guest user session
    if [ "$USER" = "$guestuser" ]; then
        rm -rf /tmp/"$guestuser"
    fi

    exit 0
```

Finally, make the two scripts executable:

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/gdm/PostLogin/Default  /etc/gdm/PostSession/Default
```

Now, just log out and you will see your new `guest` user. You can log in by selecting it and hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> when prompted for a password. The `guest` user won't be able to use `sudo` since that is the default for all users anyway. Only users explicitly mentioned in `/etc/sudoers` or those who are members of groups explicitly mentioned in `sudoers` (such as `wheel` or `sudo`, depending on your distribution) can use `sudo`.

---

If you are using a recent version of GDM, it may disable the login button while the password box is empty. To work around this you can tell GDM not to prompt for the password for specific groups. The caveat is that this will also bypass the session selection menu for members of that group. If you want to do this you should add this line **at the beginning** of `/etc/pam.d/gdm-password`:

```
auth sufficient pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup guest
```

Comment: why do you have to `chmod` those files? there is no need of that, because those scripts are run by root

Comment: @edwardtorvalds so? What difference does that make? Root can't execute non-executable files. And yes, you do need it because I tried it without making them executable and it failed. It would appear the scripts are being run directly (`/path/to/script`) and not as arguments to `sh`. Which makes sense since the examples provided included a shebang line.

Comment: On Login screen, your solution requires to press enter without entering anything which worked in 3.16. In newer gnome (probably from 3.18) you cannot press enter without entering anything. so work around is to keep hashed password section in `/etc/shadow` empty.

Comment: since `/tmp/guest/` folder does not exists on startup, shadow service of systemd is failing every time

Comment: I added a paragraph on using PAM to bypass the gdm password prompt

Comment: @MattSturgeon thanks. I assume you've tested that, right?

Comment: @terdon works fine on my arch machine. It was actually required since gdm now won't attempt to login until you have entered a password.

May be worth double checking that `useradd` always creates a default group (on all unix distros), since the PAM line uses groups.

Comment: @MattSturgeon yeah, it seems perfectly reasonable, I just asked because since I haven't tested it, I couldn't know whether it works. Great edit, thanks!

Comment: What will happen if two people (try to) login as “guest” simultaneously? Will the second one succeed?  (I don’t see anything that would stop it.) Will the `PostLogin` script run again when the second user logs in?  (This would overwrite the `/tmp/guest` **`.*`** files, which shouldn’t be an issue, since it would be (somewhat) silly for the (first) user to edit them.)  Will the `PostSession` script run when the first user logs out?  (This would delete the `/tmp/guest` directory, which might greatly inconvenience the second user.)

Comment: @G-Man yes, good point. It will probably break if two guest accounts log in at the same time.

Comment: This only worked for me after I replaced `#!/bin/sh` with `#!/bin/bash` because the `if` statement was failing with `sh` for some reason. Took me 15 minutes of testing and debugging.

Comment: I had to replace the if statement on PostSession script, not sure why, maybe it runs as gdm user and not guest?  So just tries to delete the guest drive when anyone logs out now, but it works!

Comment: @43Tesseracts sorry, my bad. The `if [[` is a bash thing, so it works if your `/bin/sh` is pointing to bash, but not if it is pointing to some other shell (e.g. `dash` as is the case on Debian and Ubuntu). The updated answer should work for all of them.

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of [logoff scripts](https://superuser.com/questions/65460/create-a-logoff-script-task-for-linux). There you can delete the home folder for your guest account and create a new one on logout. If necessary, you could make it `sudo`able by the guest account via `visudo`. Add `yourguestacc ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /path/to/script/recreating/the/home/folder`. See the [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sudo) for further information.